# Packing a jar and its dependencies into a side artifact (not producing a fat jar)

Tags: java, maven

I need package a jar A together with all its dependencies B.jar, C.jar etc. into one, flat zip file, i.e. I want to create an artifact as zip (or jar) that has the file structure

```
A.jar
B.jar
C.jar
...
```

and deploy it as side artifact for `A.jar`. Note that the artifacts should not be unpacked but just lying side by side in the side artifact, without any directory structure.

How can I achieve this with Maven?

The reason is that our production environment requires to get one zip-file that is unpacked into a directory. After that a specified Main class is started.

Comment: Did you already try something with the assembly-plugin?

Comment: No. I guess I could construct something by using dependency-copy and then assembly-plugin, but I did not want to reinvent the wheel by copying around files if there is something simpler.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a pom file which contains already the dependencies you can use the maven-assembly-plugin with an appropriate assembly descriptor and there is no need to use maven-dependency-plugin to copy something. You need to have an assembly descriptor which looks like this:

```xml
<assembly xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-1.1.0.xsd">

  <id>xyz</id>

  <formats>
      <format>zip</format>
  </formats>

  <includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>

  <dependencySets>
      <dependencySet>
          <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>
          <useProjectArtifact>false</useProjectArtifact>
          <unpack>false</unpack>
          <scope>compile</scope>
      </dependencySet>
  </dependencySets>
</assembly>
```

This should produce the appropriate zip file without any folder structure in it but containing the dependent jar file inside it.